# get value from dict when looping via ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat over an object , my object is as follows :

```
{
    "name": {
            "field_name":"date",
            "date":"00000"
        },
    "type": "timedate"
},
{
    "name":{
            "field_name": "description",
            "description":"my desc"
        },
    "type": "text"
}
```

You can see whatever the field_name value is same key exists with its value , (next key is same as field_name value) .

I can get field-name value as `name.field_name` but don't know how to get value of field exists with key same as field_name value .

I have tried this :

```
    <span data-ng-repeat="field in  fields" ng-init="val = field.name.field_name">
   {$ field.name.field_name $} : {$ field.name.field_name.val $}

    </span>
```

for first case , `val` will be set to date and This will print `{$ field.name.field_name $} - > date` . so I am thinking to get value via this `{$ field.name.field_name.val $}`  but its not working because `field_name` do not have `val` key but I want before fetch from dict it will parse val into date so that it will become `{$ field.name.field_name.val $} -> {$ field.name.field_name.date $}`

**Edit :**

I want to fetch value of date, desc and so on from name dict . but i don't know keys names these depends on value of field_name . So if I store field_name value in some variable and want to use that to fetch next value

Comment: You aren't using proper angular expression syntax. Question is very hard to understand what you are asking

Comment: @charlietfl it is feasible here or not ?

Comment: Is what feasible? Question is not clear at all

Comment: @charlietfl   I want to fetch value of `date`, `desc` and so on from `name dict` . but i don't know keys names these depends on value of `field_name` . So if I store field_name value in some variable and want to use that to fetch next value

Comment: Then update the question with that information and anything else that you misssed. You just need to use `[]` object notation

Comment: @Nano Yes offcourse , But I have used this `$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');` thats why I am using {$  $} . Bec I am using Django and angular , Django have same syntex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may get what you want, but I will use the correct angular syntax for my example

```
<span data-ng-repeat="field in  fields">
   {{ field.name.field_name }}<!-- this should print "date" at first -->
    : {{ field.name[field.name.field_name] }} <!-- this should print "00000" at first -->
</span>
```

What i did is easy, if `field.name.field_name` returns `"date"`, then you can acces the `date` property of `field.name` with the result like this `field.name[field.name.field_name]`.

I hope that is what you want.